# Special characters misform in database insert

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using UTF-8 in my HTML and have set my database table's collation to UTF-8 Unicode. The data I am saving comes from an external source, but when viewing it on the website (in UTF-8) it works out fine.

Now when I store the values from php using an insert query, values like 'Bearwölf' misform to 'BearwÃ¶lf'.

How do I get around this? I don't think there's many more details to provide, if you think of something please let me know.

Comment: What makes you think they've "misformed"?  How & where do you see the corrupted data?

Comment: By looking at the table in phpMyadmin.. This looked pretty malformed to me. Also, my cronjob that checks if this name exists and adds it if it doesn´t, doesn´t see it anymore.

I´ll quickly read the data and see how my website views it.

Comment: It's entirely possible that the connection between PHPMyadmin and MySQL is not using UTF-8, or that the PHPMyadmin page in which you're viewing the results is not encoded in UTF-8... likewise, your cronjob.  Be sure to `SET NAMES 'utf8'` after opening each connection if the client is intending to send/expecting to receive using that encoding (or else change the default).

Comment: This just went beyond my understanding.. I queried the database for the values in the bottom of the page, without any names set or whatsoever, and it prints the values correctly, like you suggested.

However, the earlier queries on the page don't. This query: `SELECT charname FROM member`, pretty much the same as the one that works, returns the names as wrecked as they are in the database when I view them. This leads my cronjob to going wrong. Even putting `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` above it didn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the API to give utf 8 encoded strings, problem solved.